# 12.04.1 Server verses 12.04.1 Desktop - Wifi issue

Tags: 12.04, wireless, server, desktop-environments

I spent a couple of days trying to figure out why I could not connect to my wifi connection running 12.04.1 Server but installing 12.04.1 Desktop connects just fine, what am I missing here?

It's the same machine:

When Server is installed I can not see the wifi card when executing

```
ifconfig
iwconfig
```

But I do see it's DISABLED when executing

```
lshw -C network

*-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 00:00:00:00:00:00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.2.0-37-generic-pae firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:feaf0000-feafffff
```

Running Desktop I navigate to Network and I'm able to see and connect to my wifi connection.

Why would this not work for Server? I really don't need the Desktop and I wanted to install server and be done with it but I would really like to know why doesn't the Server installation see / connect to my wifi?

BTW: I tried everything to enable wifi and connect to my network with server and nothing worked.

Comment: Could be because servers usually have no use for wifi connections. The Ubuntu server edition most certainly lacks the network manager, and might also lack the wireless modules and firmware. Do you have, for example `/lib/firmware`? What does `dmesg | grep wlan0` have to say?

Comment: @mikewhatever Im running the desktop version now and I see a bunch of authentication messages when running this command: dmesg | grep wlan0

Comment: ...and I assume that wireless works well, does it not?

Comment: for the Desktop version yes, for the Server version No!

Comment: ...and that is expected, as explained above.